# Enable extensions when debugging website in Chrome from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Switching from Visual Studio 2015 to 2017 I find that launching a Web API project now starts a clean, separate Chrome window. For the most part I like that, and I certainly like the idea, however: this also means **extensions are missing in Chrome**.

Is there a way to start a Web API project from Visual Studio 2017 and have Chrome launch with extensions enabled?

Or, failing that, could I revert back to the old behavior where my project is opened as a fresh tab in my existing Chrome window?

I've tried [Googling](https://www.google.nl/search?q=visual%20studio%202017%20enable%20chrome%20extensions) but found nothing. I checked the dropdown in Visual Studio with browsers (and checked the "Browse With..." dialog) but found no solution there either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you need to do is to sign-in to the instance of Chrome that VS2017 launches as the user you have all your usual extensions installed under (i.e. sign-in as the same user you usually sign-in as).

This sign-in "sticks", so extensions will load in the current - and all subsequent - debugging sessions.

Comment: Some people use Chrome with a local profile and not signed-in at all. This won't work in this case.

Answer (score 11):

You can revert back to the old behavior by

> Debug > Options > Debugging > General > (uncheck) Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.Net (Chrome and IE).

*Is there a way to start a Web API project from Visual Studio 2017 and have Chrome launch with extensions enabled?*

Yes, but it works for one project only, mean you need to **re-install** extensions when you launch a brand new project. I tried Sync in Chrome (not work).

In my opinion, there are something to do with Chrome remote debugging protocol profile. I hope someone knows about Chrome can give a final solution for this.

you can study more here:  [remote debugging protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855773/enable-extensions-when-debugging-website-in-chrome-from-visual-studio-2017)

---

There is a way that you no need to change anything. But it annoying.

Because Visual Studio 2017 use an instance of Chrome for debug mode when you hit F5, so you can leave that debug mode instance with remote debugging protocol open, and use your default Chrome instance with full extensions. Just copy and paste the link into your favorite Chrome instance.

Cheer! hope it help.

Comment: The key for me here (in my case with a Blazor app) was that you just ned to re-install the extension. They aren't actually disabled.