# How to View a SAML Response in chrome while debugging using visual studio

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, saml-2.0

I wanted to view SAML response in chrome while debugging. I have installed `SAML DevTools extension`. When i browse web site in chrome and then press F12 to open developer tools, i see tab for SAML and i can see the response.

However, i'm developing an application using Visual Studio 2017, and the application makes call to external `Idp` to get SAML response. I set my visual studio to open in chrome, and start debugging the application. It opens in chrome, then i press F12 to open developer tools, however this time i don't see SAML extension.
The SAML extension is only available when browse the web site without debugging

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable extensions when debugging website in Chrome from Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855773/enable-extensions-when-debugging-website-in-chrome-from-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing Chrome-specific work? If you can use FireFox I'd recommend using saml tracer (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/), or just using Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler). These are the best tools for SAML tracing in my experience.

Comment: yes i use fiddler , however the SAML response in fiddler in encoded. It does not decode it

Comment: Fiddler can decode SAML, along with a number of other things. Highlight the response, right-click, choose "Send to TextWizard..." and then choose the appropriate encoding that you are trying to decode.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered here:
[Enable extensions when debugging website in Chrome from Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42855773/enable-extensions-when-debugging-website-in-chrome-from-visual-studio-2017)

In a nutshell, sign into Chrome that is opened - it will install your extensions, and persist your sign-in, allowing you to use the SAML extension.